# Episerver - How to select Items from List<IContent> based on the ContentType

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-8

I have a list of IContent Items, I know that one of the items will be of a particular type.

Currently I am getting this Item with this code:

```
var result = ancestors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContentTypeID == 104);
```

I know the name of MyType how can do this without an hard coded Id?

If this number is diffrent in mulitiple enviorments the code will fail, can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just type-check it like:

`var result = ancestors.SingleOrDefault(x => x is MyContentType);`

Or:

`var result = ancestors.OfType<MyContentType>();`

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question?